# How to resolve error "groovy.json,version=[2.4,3) -- Cannot be resolved" on Apache Sling 8 - Groovy Support?

Tags: sling

I would like to use Groovy scripting in Apache Sling. I have installed Sling 8 and Bundle: Scripting Groovy V 1.0.2 on top. However, I am getting the following error on installed bundle.

```
groovy.json,version=[2.4,3) -- Cannot be resolved
groovy.lang,version=[2.4,3) -- Cannot be resolved
groovy.text,version=[2.4,3) -- Cannot be resolved
javax.script from org.apache.felix.framework (0)
org.apache.sling.commons.classloader,version=[1.0,2) from org.apache.sling.commons.classloader (84)
org.apache.sling.scripting.api,version=[2.1,3) from org.apache.sling.scripting.api (107)
org.codehaus.groovy.util,version=[2.4,3) -- Cannot be resolved
```

Am I missing some other dependency bundle? How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Groovy scripting bundle only provides the glue between Groovy and Sling. You also need to install the Groovy bundles.

The ones that we use right now for testing (see [launchpad/testing: model.txt](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/4ed3b82885bde2b0356ea91b68cb3f0978428931/contrib/launchpad/testing/src/main/provisioning/model.txt#L51-L53) ) are

```
org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.4.5
org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-json/2.4.5
org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-templates/2.4.5
```

Comment: Are these OSGi bundles that are installed through system console? How to obtain the bundles you mentioned? Can you please describe briefly how to install?

Comment: Yes, you can install them through the system console. They are available on maven central , see for instance http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.codehaus.groovy|groovy-json|2.4.5|jar

Comment: Thanks for your help! I downloaded the Groovy SDK and copied the 3 jars mentioned above. Installed these jars as OSGi bundles and now groovy scripting works.